# SwitchPreference null on lower sdk version (api level 21)

Tags: android

```
OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    @Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

I continuously receive a NPE when I attempt to see if one of my switchpreferences are checked, as shown below:

```
switchPending = (SwitchPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("pendingAlert");
```

it crashes on the next line:

```
mListener.setSwitchPending(switchPending.isChecked());
```

But only on lower apis (im running my emulator at v21). Why is this? The complete trace is this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.maplesyrupindustries.j.airportmeet.SettingsFragment$OnFragmentInteractionListener.setSwitchPending(java.lang.Boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at com.maplesyrupindustries.j.airportmeet.SettingsFragment.onCreateView(SettingsFragment.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
                                                                                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
                                                                                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
                                                                                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
                                                                                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:483)
                                                                                      at android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:149)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1237)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1085)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1611)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:671)
                                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1319)
                                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:736)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.
```

Comment: Actually it says mListener is null , post full code

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by overriding the deprecated (for sdk 23 and above) onAttach method. So now I have 2 onAttach methods. The one used for SDK < 23 is as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
        mContext = activity;
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) mContext;
    }
}
```